# Two variables in one loop

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, powershell-5.0

I am currently working on a script which should query a machine by hostname and ip.

```
$IP = (get-content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PowerShell\ips.txt")
$hostname = (get-content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PowerShell\hostnames.txt")
```

Now I need to insert the `$IP` and `$hostname` into a string.

```
write-host "This is my $IP, this is my $hostname"
```

So far I tried to use a for loop and increment I every loop, but instead of taking just one insert from my txt file it took all.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 1; $i++ )
```

How can I achieve that my loop takes one line from the one file and one from the other?

Comment: That question does more but the set up you are looking for is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `$IP` is an array of IPs with the same length as `$hostname`:

```
$IP = (get-content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PowerShell\ips.txt")
$hostname = (get-content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\PowerShell\hostnames.txt")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $IP.Length; $i++ )
{
    write-host "This is my $($IP[$i]), this is my $($hostname[$i])"
}
```

The `Get-Content` cmdlet returns an array of strings so you have to access the current line by *index*. **Note:**  You also have to use a *subexpression* using `$()` to interpolate the string.